# Set variable with Scope Identity after executing different stored proc

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to set a declared variable in a stored procedure after making use of another stored procedure to `INSERT` a 'Case' first.

The pseudo code looks like this:

```
DECLARE @CaseId variable
INSERT Case into Case table
SET @CaseId using SCOPE_IDENTITY

IF Case.CaseID = @CaseId
--rest of script
```

The below script works as expected for me:

```
INSERT INTO Case (CaseRef, [Source], DateCreated, CaseType)
VALUES (@caseRef, @source, @dateCreated, @caseType)
SET @caseID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

I've tried with the below script but it doesn't seem to set the variable. Is this possible? Or must I set it the way I'm doing in the above script?

```
EXEC sp_InsertCase @caseRef, @source, @dateCreated, @caseType
SET @caseID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scope_identity()` does what it says on the tin - it gives you the last identity value generated *in the current scope*. A stored procedure defines a scope. So when the stored procedure that causes the identity value to be generated exits, you're no longer in the scope where the value was generated, so `scope_identity()` can't tell you anything.

What you can do is capture the `scope_identity()` value into a variable inside the stored procedure, and return it as an output parameter:

```
create table t(i int identity(1,1), j int);
go
create proc insert_and_get_scope @scopeid int = null output as
begin
   insert t(j) values (1);
   set @scopeid = scope_identity();
end
go

declare @scopeid int;
exec insert_and_get_scope @scopeid output;
select @scopeid;
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining how Scope works. I don't need to unnecessarily complicate it so I'll just stick to getting the identity value "in the current scope"as you said

Answer (score 1):

You can see from the example below:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [dbo].[StackOverflow];

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[StackOverflow]
(
    [RowID] INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
);

GO

CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_StackOverflow]
AS
BEGIN;
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[StackOverflow]
    DEFAULT VALUES;
END;


GO

EXEC [dbo].[sp_StackOverflow];
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

it is not working, [because](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/scope-identity-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) it is not in the current scope:

> Returns the last identity value inserted into an identity column in
> the same scope. A scope is a module: a stored procedure, trigger,
> function, or batch. Therefore, if two statements are in the same
> stored procedure, function, or batch, they are in the same scope.

but you can try this:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [dbo].[StackOverflow];

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[StackOverflow]
(
    [RowID] INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
);

GO

CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_StackOverflow]
(
    @RowID BIGINT OUTPUT
)
AS
BEGIN;
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[StackOverflow]
    DEFAULT VALUES;

    SET @RowID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
END;


GO


DECLARE @RowID BIGINT;

EXEC [dbo].[sp_StackOverflow] @RowID = @RowID OUTPUT;
SELECT @RowID;
```